# how to check if the mail I have sent from laravel has been delivered to recipient or not?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10, laravel-mail

I have searched the entire internet but found nothing for my problem. I am using Laravel 10 for my project to send bulk mails. Laravel is sending the mails to the provided mail address. But the problem: Is there any way to check the status of a mail delivered successfully to the recipient or not?

I found solutions in many forums telling that to use `Mail::failures()`. But this method is not available in Laravel anymore. So what is the proper way to get the status of the mail delivered to the recipient mail or not? Please help.

My code in controller:

```php
try {
    foreach ($emails as $key => $email) {
        $result = Mail::to($email)->send(new MarketingMail($email_content));
    }
                
} catch (Exception $e) {
    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'Email not valid',
        'status' => 500
    ], 500);
}
```

Comment: As I know, in Laravel, you can't check mail delivered.

Comment: What email provider are you using? Some of the email providers eg: Mailgun, Mailchimp, etc already provides these reports in their portals. Email system delivery is kind of complex. There are also cases of email bounce or invalid addresses, these providers have handled this well.

Comment: I am using smtp.

Answer (score -1):

A popular marketing method called the pixel approach, to implement it you can create a route in your application that corresponds to an image URL. This route will handle requests made to this URL, and you can use it to mark an email as delivered in your system. The concept is to embed a small, transparent image in your email templates, and when the recipient opens the email and loads the image, it triggers the route and updates the email status.

For example, in your `web.php` routes file:

```php
Route::get('/images/email-delivered-event/{email_id_or_any_identifier}', function ($email_id_or_any_identifier) {
    // Find the corresponding model instance based on the provided identifier
    $model = YourModel::findOrFail($email_id_or_any_identifier);

    // Update the model to mark the email as delivered
    $model->is_delivered = true;
    $model->save();
    // Or Consider this as an event listener to your email delivered event you can use any action

    // You can return an empty response as the image, or a 1x1 transparent pixel
    return response('', 200)->header('Content-Type', 'image/png');

});
```

Your generated image URL should look like

```
https://yourdomain.com/images/email-delivered-event/4356349859348759
```

#### Note

Remember that some email clients may block image loading by default for security and privacy reasons. In such cases, this pixel approach might not work.

#### Disclaimer

Always consider the privacy implications and comply with regulations when using such tracking mechanisms.

Comment: Couldn't understand fully. Can you please kindly add more details to your answer ?

Comment: I updated the answer, I hope it is more clear now. I also added a Disclaimer please review it.

Comment: _"and you can use it to mark an email as delivered in your system"_ - the pixel will only be requested, when the recipient _opens_ the mail. Opened emails will certainly have been successfully delivered, sure - but you can't tell anything about mails that might have been successfully delivered, but not _opened_ yet, via this method. And the "some email clients" that might block this, are probably rather most of them in reality, at least in current day default settings.

Comment: @CBroe unfortunately yes.

Comment: Great idea. I will try it and come back as soon as possible.

Comment: Can you give an example of how should I embed the image in my blade file and link that with route ?

Comment: @TanjibRubayet It's a meh idea which has been aleady discarded. Most clients blocks images now a days unless the user specifically opts for images (which most won't).